# Why does the root of this AVL tree keep being treated as null even though it has been populated with objects?

Tags: java, recursion, search, null, avl-tree

This is the insertion method:

```
private Node insertNode(Person data, Node root)
{
    //check whether the node is null or not
    if (root == null)
        root = new Node(data);
        //insert a node in case when the given data is lesser than the data of the root node
    else if (getCountCommon(data, root.getRoot()) == 0)
    {
        root.setLeftSubTree(insertNode(data, root.getLeftSubTree()));
        if(getHeight(root.getLeftSubTree()) - getHeight(root.getRightSubTree()) == 2 )
            if(getCountCommon(data, root.getLeftSubTree().getRoot()) == 0)
                root = rotateWithleftSubTree(root);
            else
                root = doubleWithleftSubTree(root);
    }
    else if(getCountCommon(data, root.getRoot()) > 0)
    {
        root.setRightSubTree(insertNode(data, root.getRightSubTree()));
        if(getHeight(root.getRightSubTree()) - getHeight(root.getLeftSubTree()) == 2 )
            if(getCountCommon(data, root.getRightSubTree().getRoot()) > 0)
                root = rotateWithrightSubTree(root);
            else
                root = doubleWithrightSubTree(root);
    }
    else
          ;// if the data is already present in the tree, we will do nothing

    root.setHeight(getMaxHeight(getHeight(root.getLeftSubTree()), getHeight(root.getRightSubTree())) + 1);

    return root;

}
```

And this is the method I use to get a count of all nodes:

```
private int getTotalNumberOfNodes(Node root)
{
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int size = 1;
        size = size + getTotalNumberOfNodes(root.getLeftSubTree());
        size = size + getTotalNumberOfNodes(root.getRightSubTree());
        return size;
    }
}
```

When I populate the tree with an ArrayList of 20000 objects...

```
System.out.println("\nPopulating tree with data from personList...");

for (int index=0; index<size; index++){

    personTree.insertNode(personList.get(index));
}

System.out.println("Tree populated.");

//Checking number of nodes in tree
System.out.println("Number of nodes in tree: " + personTree.getTotalNumberOfNodes() + "\n");
```

I get this output:
Populating tree with data from personList...
Tree populated.
Number of nodes in tree: 20000

Then, when I attempt to search the tree...

```
Tree class:
public void searchData(Person data){
    searchData(getRoot(), data);
}

public void searchData(Node root, Person data)
{
    Person check = new Person();

    if(root == null)
    {
        System.out.println(data.getFirstName() + " was not found.");
    }
    else if (root.getRoot() == data)
    {
        System.out.println(data.getFirstName() + "was found!");
        check = root.getRoot();
    }
    else
    {
        if (getCountCommon(root.getRoot(), data) == 0){
            root = root.getLeftSubTree();
            searchData(root, data);
        } else if (getCountCommon(root.getRoot(), data) > 0){
            root = root.getRightSubTree();
            searchData(root, data);
        }
    }
}

Main:
System.out.println("\nSearching tree for '" + personList.get(6889).getFirstName() + " " + personList.get(6889).getLastName() + "'...");
personTree.searchData(personList.get(6889));
```

I keep getting this output:
Searching tree for 'Hugh Senior'...
Hugh was not found.

When I checked to see if there was anything at the root using this code:

```
System.out.println("\nData at tree root is: \n" + personTree.getRoot().getRoot());
```

I get this output, which tells me it's not empty:

```
Data at tree root is: 
First Name:    Robert
Last Name:   Bell
Telephone:   8766554539
Email:       RoBell15@hotmail.com
Community:   Liguanea
School:      Camperdown
Employer:    NCB
Privacy:     Y
     ---Activity/Activities---
```

On some occasions, when I directly called the root accessor from the tree class and tried using it as input directly into the second search method, it threw errors saying my root was null. And the warnings in IntelliJ are telling me that nothing past the first if statement in searchData(Node root, Person data) gets checked since the root is always null.

I tried directly checking the tree's root again in main, and it shows that data is there so I'm stumped.

Comment: Inserting has to be done as `root = insertNode(data, root);`. Because assigning to the local parameter `root` does not assign to the passed global variable `root`, In java `f(x)` will never assign to a passed variable `x` _(=pass-by-value)_. Better also rename the root parameter to `node` or such, as root means top node.

Comment: @JoopEggen Did you mean I should replace all instances of 'root' with 'node' inside the method? I've done that and now I'm getting a StackOverflow error that's saying I should create a breakpoint to resolve it

Comment: Inside `insertNode` a rename of _root_ to _node_ is more clear and should not have changed anything.  The stacktrace itself should already show where an endless loop happens.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks for correcting me on that. I'm still having the same problem with my search though. The suggestion I get from my compiler when looking at the code tells me that the check variable is never used or accessed because the root is null (it's throwing a NullPointerException). Any tips on that?

Comment: Sorry for the late return here. No, I have no idea. Keep thing readable, a classs in its own file, the usage separate. And the debugger is your best friend to inspect along what code the program runs.